# Duplicate materials - to create another similar yet modified one

Tags: materials

I have a material that took some time to create. I want another one like that, except for the base colours (I'm using a toon setup found online and I want e.g. brown for wood and grey for metal). 
Please be advised that the question is NOT about copying a mat to another object.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The '+' sign near the material header (on right from its name) in the material panel ?

Comment: Lemon, I think you may write an answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the *plus sign* on the right of the material name to copy and replace your current material.

As you can see below, the former material is still available.

[image]

This *plus sign* is available for many Blender objects, like textures, particle systems or others...

But you may notice that it does not work properly in the node editor :

[image]

So, use it in the properties panel...